# Add Paragraph Line Spacing To A Custom Ribbon In Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ribbon

I have literally been racking my brain for months trying to find a way to make the paragraph "Line spacing" and "At" fields appear in my custom ribbon. As you can see by the screenshot below, I've circled the tabbed area on my custom ribbon where I want it to appear.

http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p278/cashflow71/RibbonScreenshotStackoverflow01.png

I have easily been able to make the **Before** and **After** paragraph spacing show up by using the following coding in **Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office**:

```
    <group id="sampleGroup7" label="Before/After">

    <box id="boxGeneralForms1" boxStyle="horizontal" visible="true">

      <control idMso="ParagraphSpacingBefore"/>
      <control idMso="ParagraphSpacingIncrease" visible="false"/>


    </box>  

    <box id="boxGeneralForms2" boxStyle="horizontal" visible="true">

        <control idMso="ParagraphSpacingAfter" label="After:   "/>
        <control idMso="ParagraphSpacingDecrease" visible="false"/>
```

But I am unable to add the two fields that normally sit to the right of it in the paragraph pop-up menu. To be more specific, what I'm looking to add is the information circled in the screenshot below:

http://i130.photobucket.com/albums/p278/cashflow71/RibbonScreenshotStackoverflow02.png

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a control reference for Ribbon XML Office controls for each version of Office. The references for Office 2010 and Office 2013 can be found below:

[Office 2010 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)

[Office 2013 Help Files: Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

These spreadsheets reveal the identifiers for any Microsoft Office control you'd wish to re-purpose.

I looked up the Word reference and saw that the idMso for the first control is LineSpacingMenu. I added it to the XML with these lines:

```
      <box id="boxGeneralForms3" boxStyle="horizontal" visible="true">
        <control idMso="LineSpacingMenu" label="Line Spacing:"></control>
      </box>
```

I did not see an idMso for the second control (the one that allows manual adjustment of the line spacing by inputting a value), but this can be re-created with code by adding an editBox to the Ribbon XML and tying it to the value for line spacing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your informed response, joeschwa. I forgot to mention I was familiar with that naming and tried variances of this a while back but perhaps your post has the exact variance in the wording that may make it work. Unfortunately, I won't be able to test it this moment as I return to work on Tuesday.